# How to hide address bar using javascript window.open?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, address-bar

I want to disable the address bar using javascript `window.open`.
Also the script should work in IE, Safari and chrome. Any suggestions.

Comment: As you probably know, there are the well known `location=no`, `addressbar=no` etc, but not all browsers follow this. Some of this is because of security reasons.

Comment: Since the release of Firefox 3 it is not possible to hide the address bar. The option dom.disable_window_open_feature.location is by default set to true. As Christian mentioned, some browsers have strict rules when it comes to security.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(untested)

```
function openWindow(){
var browser=navigator.appName;
if (browser==”Microsoft Internet Explorer”)
{
window.opener=self;

}
window.open(‘filename.htm’,'null’,'width=900,height=750,
toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,resizable =yes’);
window.moveTo(0,0);
window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height-100);
self.close();
}
```

Got this from http://saher42.wordpress.com/2006/08/10/hiding-the-address-bar-on-pageload-using-javascript/.

Comment: This kind of code hasn't worked for a long time (since versions of IE7, at least).

Answer (score 13):

`location` is the window feature you want to set to `no` or `0` to hide the address bar.

*Opinionated Advice*: You can't rely on popups showing because most people have popup blockers installed to curb abuse, so if you can get away with it, don't use a pop up at all! Use something like the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) plugin.

*Example:*

window.open("http://www.mydomain.com/mypage.htm", "mywindow", "**location=0**,menubar=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,width=100,height=100");

*Format*

window.open( [Url] [, Name] [, Features] [, History] )

*Window features you can control*

- **status**   The status bar at the bottom of the window.
- **toolbar**  The standard browser toolbar, with buttons such as Back and Forward.
- **location**     The Location entry field where you enter the URL.
- **menubar**  The menu bar of the window
- **resizable**    Allow/Disallow the user to resize the window.
- **scrollbars**   Enable the scrollbars if the document is bigger than the window
- **height**   Specifies the height of the window in pixels. (example: height=’350′)
- **width**    Specifies the width of the window in pixels.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation. some attributes like location, status, resizable, etc works only in IE but didn't in other browsers like FF, Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Also you have to enable *window.open* to hide the address bar in Firefox, which is disabled by default. Go to `about:config`, search for `disable_window_open`, so you can see [all *window.open* feature disabling options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3etkQ.png), including **`dom.disable_window_open_feature.location`**, which is responsible for the address bar not hiding. Set it to `false`.

Comment: This may not be the best answer for the OP, but it's exactly what I needed! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Type in the address bar of Firefox like this  about:config,

search for disable_window_open, so you can see all window.open feature

Comment: The question was about how to disable address bar programmatically in Javascript.

Comment: he wants it in javascript not by browser config.

Comment: May not be irrelevant. See Bene Laci's answer.