# Open a new window with certain constraints

Tags: javascript, browser, window, constraints

Using JavaScript I want to open a new browser window with following characteristics. Please advise:

1. Open a new window (not a new tab)
2. New window shouldn't have toolbar, addressbar, menubar, statusbar
3. New window should be maximized
4. New window shouldn't be resizable
5. From the new window, I should not be able to open a new tab
6. The above should work with all modern browsers

**Update**: I have used the code from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp with undesired results across browsers. For example, location=no still shows address bar in FireFox.

Comment: wow, dumping requirements and expecting code?

Comment: Are you hiring someone for a job or asking for help?

Comment: I'm asking for help. I thought it was evident.

Comment: This question has been closed for reasons like it is 'ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered'. I wonder which part of the question qualifies for any of the specified reasons! Funny indeed!!

Answer (score 1):

> For example, location=no still shows address bar in FireFox.

[How to hide address bar in Firefox using javascript window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664992/how-to-hide-address-bar-in-firefox-using-javascript-window-open)

Setting the browser GUI is not a programmer's business. Users define it, not you.

Comment: Thanks Kolyunya, especially when others are being so judgmental & cynical about my question.

Comment: Doesn't the question you linked to have an answer using `location=no` - could you explain why that would work when Kabeer already said it doesn't? There's also a comment under that question saying it can't be done in FF...

Comment: This is the answer to your question - it's just impossible to hide address bar in new versions of firefox and other browsers. In fact you can not hide **most** of gui elements. This is made in order to protect users from some crazy tricks, when hackers substitute OS windows to a browser window.

Comment: This means, setting the browser GUI is not a programmer's business. Users define it, not you.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't override the browser settings, it will open in a tab if the user wants that.
2. You can try `menubar=0,location=0,status=0` in the feature string, but it's not likely that you will be able to remove all of them. The address field is generally impossible to remove in most browsers.
3. You can't open a maximised window. You can try `fullscreen=1` in the feature string, which would give a similar effect.
4. You can try `resizable=0` in the feature string, but it's not likely that it will make the window impossible to resize.
5. That's not possible. You may be able to remove some of the ways to open a new window/tab (e.g. the menu), but the feature to open new windows can't be disabled.
6. The support for this varies across browsers, you will never be able to make all this work in all browsers.

Look at Microsofts documentation of the [open method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open) at Mozilla for a list of supported features.