# How to disable copy paste of browsers url in java script or jquery?

Tags: javascript

How to disable copy paste of browsers URL in java script or j query. I have tried a lot from Google but i have not found exact solution for tackling this problem. All solution I got is either disable body of web browser or disable any particular fields.

I am Stuck on this problem please any one help me out.

Browser Support for IE9 and firefox 14+.

Thanks

Comment: I think it is impossible

Comment: presumably you _can_ make the site appear in a window without an address bar, in which case there's nothing to copy. Not sure that is what you are asking though... In case it is, there is some information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664992/how-to-hide-address-bar-in-firefox-using-javascript-window-open)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.  And as for why people are down-voting you, even though your question is somewhat well-formed, I'd assume that's because people absolutely hate this idea.  So don't do it.

Comment: If a client has the requirement that a purple elephant be slaughtered for lunch in the office each day, what will you do?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The address bar is a part of the browser, and is not accessible to your webpage.

Comment: I think there will some solution...please help me

Comment: There is no solution! What makes you think there is?